# Qt conversion error when connecting slots and signals

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class that inherits from QListWidget called `Menu` and I am trying to connect this the class' signals to a widget's slots.

```
class Menu : QListWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    Menu(Config &config, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Menu();

public slots:
    void itemChanged(QListWidgetItem *item);

signals:
    void clickedItemChanged(std::string item);

private:
    std::vector<QListWidgetItem*> items;

};

// in another widget connect the signals and slots 
connect(menu, SIGNAL(clickedItemChanged(std::string)),
        this, SLOT(menuItemChanged(std::string)));
```

But the compilation failed, saying *cannot cast 'Menu' to its private base class 'const QObject'*. The signature of the slot matches that of the signal, and the widget class to which the slot belongs holds a reference to `Menu`. What caused the problem and how should I solve it?

Comment: did you `#include` the header in which `Menu` is defined into the cpp file where you call connect?

Comment: `std::string` doesn't work like Qt containers so copying is (usually) quite expensive, consider changing your signal and slot signatures to use const references

Comment: Why are you inheriting *privately* from `QListWidget`?  That makes the base class inaccessible. Use `public` inheritance.

Comment: @G.M. didn't notice that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IlBeldus Got it!

Comment: @IlBeldus connections where argument `std::string` will work for direct connections, only in case of queued connections error will be reported on a runtime. This issue will not appear in build time. You can [register](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1) `std::string` as a type and it should work always.

Comment: @MarekR wrong tag but insightful comment

Comment: Off-topic: you should consider changing your `connect()` calls to modern C++ syntax, so that they're actually checked at compile time: `connect(menu, &Menu::clickedItemChanged,  this, &YourClassName::menuItemChanged);`